# Subtract values matching index in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is somewhat basic, but I couldn't find a simple answer. In Python have a dataframe *A* like this:

```
  ItemId      Price
  -------   -------
0   a1         10.0
1   a1         15.0
2   a2          8.0
3   a3          7.0
```

And a second one, *B*, like this, where item ids appear only once, they are index:

```
ItemId   Discount
------  ---------
a1            0.2
a2            0.5
a4            0.3
```

I want to subtract 'Discount' values (from *B*) from 'Price' of dataframe *A*, by matching Item Ids, like this:

```
ItemId   Price
-------  -----
a1         9.8
a1        14.8
a2         7.5
a3         7.0
```

How can I do this in a efficient way, taking into account that actual dataframes have thousands of rows and many other columns?

Comment: In B  `ItemId` is a column or the index ?

Comment: @SeaBean as in the question: "And a second one, B, like this, where item ids appear only once, **they are index**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the discounts using the price df with `fill_value=0`:

```py
A.set_index('ItemId').Price - B.Discount.reindex(A.ItemId, fill_value=0)

# ItemId
# a1     9.8
# a1    14.8
# a2     7.5
# a3     7.0
# dtype: float64
```

Timings of the current answers:

[image: timings of map vs reindex vs merge]

```py
map_ = lambda A, B: A.Price - A.ItemId.map(B.Discount).fillna(0)
reindex_ = lambda A, B: A.set_index('ItemId').Price - B.Discount.reindex(A.ItemId, fill_value=0)
merge_ = lambda A, B: A.merge(B, on='ItemId', how='left').eval('Price - Discount.fillna(0)')
```

Comment: Aren't those expensive operations for large dataframes? Do you know how do they compare to the map solution posted by @not_speshal above?

Comment: you're right about `a3`. To be fair, I've edited the question to consider it after the answer was posted. Anyway, just by adding `fillna` would do the trick: `dfA["Price"]-dfA["ItemId"].map(dfB["Discount"]).fllna(0)`

Comment: @thatOldITGuy so i've pushed the benchmarks as far as my laptop can handle (10^8 rows in `A` and 10^4 rows in B), and it seems `map`/`reindex` are pretty similar for larger dfs

Comment: very interesting. Since yours is the most complete answer I'm accepting it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `map`:

```
>>> dfA["Price"]-dfA["ItemId"].map(dfB["Discount"])
0     9.8
1    14.8
2     7.5
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `merge` to align the frames on the "ItemId" column and `eval` to operate on those aligned columns:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, on="ItemId", how="left").eval("Price - Discount.fillna(0)")
0     9.8
1    14.8
2     7.5
dtype: float64
```